# Shiny - how to change the font size in select tags?

Tags: r, shiny

How can I change the font size in select tags?

I tried with this code below but the font size does not change at all.

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(

  sidebarPanel(

    # Change the font size.
    tags$style(type='text/css', "select {font-size: 32px !important} "),

    # Species/ pollutant options
    selectInput(
        inputId = "species",
        label = "Species:",
        choices = c(...)
        ),
   ....
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You had the right idea, but the select input in shiny actually uses selectize JavaScript to show the UI instead of the traditional `select` HTML tag. That's why your CSS isn't catching.

What you want instead of the `select` CSS is `".selectize-input { font-size: 32px; }`

However, if you only have that CSS then the dropdown menu options will still be the default size and also there will be no padding around the text which looks very awkward. Here's some CSS you might want to use:

```
.selectize-input { font-size: 32px; line-height: 32px;}
.selectize-dropdown { font-size: 28px; line-height: 28px; }
```

So adding that to an app gives this:

```
runApp(shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    tags$style(type='text/css', ".selectize-input { font-size: 32px; line-height: 32px;} .selectize-dropdown { font-size: 28px; line-height: 28px; }"),
    selectInput("test","Test", 1:5)
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
  }
))
```

Comment: is it possible to change font-size for many selectInput buttons, which id's starts from 'SelectInputXYZ...' ? I know that if you want to use specific button, instead of '.selectize-input' you use '#SelectInputXYZ1', but I tried to put it in renderUI in loop and it didn't work.

Comment: can you also change the font of the selectInput labels?

Comment: these are all possible, you just need to use CSS (learning CSS is very useful!)

Answer (score 1):

Adding (#) before select will also solve your issue.

tags$style(type='text/css', "#select {font-size: 32px !important} "),