# change CSS of single element from shinyWidgets in flexdashboard

Tags: css, r, shiny, flexdashboard, shinywidgets

Related to questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53178953/changing-css-styling-of-single-shinywidgets-element-using-shinythemes-packages) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61048036/changing-css-params-of-a-dropdownbutton-from-shinywidgets), I would like to change the CSS of a pickerInput menu from ShinyWidgets.  I am using flexdashboard and I would like the styling to match exactly that from the selectInput menu.  I realize I can do this by setting the overall theme in the YAML to bootstrap, but I'd prefer not to use a global solution.

````
---
title: "Testing picker styles"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard
runtime: shiny
---
  
```{r setup, include=F}
library(shiny)
library(flexdashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)
```

Column 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
  
```{r}
selectInput(inputId = "id1", label = "Select input", choices = attr(UScitiesD, "Labels"))
pickerInput(inputId = "id2", label = "Picker input", choices = attr(UScitiesD, "Labels"))
```
````

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`pickerInput` is styled like a Bootstrap button, and {flexdashboard} use Bootswatch's Cosmo theme (https://bootswatch.com/3/cosmo/) that's why it appears black.

You can change the class of the button with :

```
options = pickerOptions(style = "btn-link")
```

(in `pickerInput` arguments)

[image]

Or you can overwrite the base style like this :

```
options = list("style-base" = "form-control", style = "")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Victorp, anyway to make the heights the same and round the corners?  I was looking for literal "exact".