# How to make sure only one radioButton can be selected from 4 different radioButton groups R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am building a Shiny app for weather data, where I want to allow the user to choose a variable from one of four different groups to analyze (weather, wind, soil, station).  My user interface looks like this:

[image]

First, the separation is superficial, really, since I will be creating the same analyses for all variables - I just don't want an ugly mess of a radio button list.  If I could use a single inputID for all four sets of variables, I would.  So I have to ask, is that possible, somehow?  My guess is that it's not, but if it is, I would love to hear about it.

So, what I need to do is set up code so that only one option from 1 group can be selected at a time.  Is there a way to "turn off" or ignore the other 3 groups when the user selects a variable from the 4th group?  Would something like this work?

```
 observeEvent(input$Group1, {
     input$Group2 = NULL,
     input$Group3 = NULL,
     input$Group4 = NULL
 )}
```

The problem with this method (if it would even work) is that I would need 4 separate observeEvent functions to handle it.  Is this the way it would have to be, or is there a better way to do this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you accept a different visualization, a grouped `selectizeInput` could achieve very simply your goal :

```
ui <- fluidPage(sidebarLayout(
  sidebarPanel(
    # a select input
    selectizeInput('selectvar', 'Variables', choices = list(
      `Weather Variables` = c('TA','RW','TA120','PP','PA','SD','XR','TA40'),
      `Wind Variables` = c('US','UE','UH','UD','UG'),
      `Soil Variables` = c('TB4','TVB','MV2','MV20','TV2','TV20')
    ))
  ),
  mainPanel(
    verbatimTextOutput('value')
  )
))



server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$value <- renderPrint({
    input$selectvar
  })
}

shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that will work for now.  Do you happen to know how to adjust the font size of the group headings ("Weather Variables", etc)?

Comment: I didn't try, but this could help : https://stackoverflow.com/a/30523018/13513328

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I did try that, but only actual variables change font size, not the different headings.